# Нарисовать крест на Python

Tags: python

помогите нарисовать крест на Python символами ^

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали сделать? На чем споткнулись, что не получается?

Answer (score 6):

```
print(" ^ ")
print("^^^")
print(" ^ ")
```

Comment: Нужен крест типо Х с помощью символа ^